# Nginx - convert string to number

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

The question is simple let's say I have a variable in nginx:

```
set $test $upstream_status;
```

And now the status in the variable will be for example "200". How I can convert this variable to number in order to use it like so:

```
return $test "test";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every nginx variable is a string, with the only exception of [`$remote_binary_addr`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_binary_remote_addr) one (which is still a binary-packed string of 4 or 16 bytes length after all) and a few others. However not every nginx directive allows you to use variable(s) to specify its parameters, and the HTTP return code for the `return` directive is exactly one of those cases.

Moreover, whatever you are trying to do, you definitely trying to do it in a wrong way. All the directives from the [ngx_http_rewrite_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) module (including the `return` one) are being executed at the very early stage of request processing, before anything is being send to the upstream, not even speaking about something that should be received. Usually such a thing can be achieved using the `proxy_intercept_errors on;` setting and specifying an [`error_page`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) handler for the specific upstream return code, e.g.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass ...
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 301 @handler_301;
    error_page 302 @handler_302;
    ...
}
location @handler_301 {
    # you are free to use 'return 301 "anything"' here
    ...
}
location @handler_302 {
    ...
}
...
```

However the only return codes you can intercept with this are 300 and above.